# Unity C#. Анимация интерфейса по кнопке с задержкой

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация, ui, animator

Сразу добавлю, что я совсем новичок, перед вопросом много перерыла, но не разобралась.

Ситуация: есть кнопки меню на основной сцене. По нажатию кнопки1 выезжает панель1, кнопки2 - панель2 и тд.

Мне нужно анимировать выезжание этих панелей следующим образом. При нажатии любой кнопки выезжает соответствующая ей панель, при нажатии этой кнопки повторно панель заезжает назад. При этом если нажать сначала кнопку1 (панель1 здесь выехала) а потом сразу кнопку2, должна воспроизвестись анимация закрытия панели1 и следом открытия панели2.

На данный момент у меня все анимации сделаны внутри юнити, работают, условия для анимаций написаны и тоже в целом работают, **НО** не могу сообразить, как реализовать задержку между анимациями "закрыть панель1" и "открыть панель2". Иначе сейчас анимация закрытия не успевает воспроизвестись, так как сразу же вопроизводится анимация открытия второй панели. Очень надеюсь, что написано понятно.

Прикладываю кусок скрипта с примером реализации условия запуска анимаций.

```
    if (settingsIsClosed & !shopIsClosed)
{
    animMenu.Play("ShopClose");
    shopIsClosed = true;
    //в этом месте нужна задержка ?
    animMenu.Play("SettingsOpen");
    settingsIsClosed = false;
}
```

Прошу подсказать, как реализовать саму эту задержку. Или возможно нужно вообще все переделывать иначе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, насколько правилен такой подход, но вопрос был решен мной следующим образом:

1. Каждый запуск анимации обернула в функцию.
2. Проигрывание каждой второй анимации во всех ифах завернула в Invoke

В результате вместо куска скрипта из вопроса получилось:

```
if (settingsIsClosed & !shopIsClosed)
{
    ShopClose();
    Invoke(nameof(SettingsOpen), 0.5f);
}
```

Задержку в 0,5 секунд поставила из соображения, что все анимации длятся именно столько, поэтому анимации работают плавно на данном этапе.